Repairs return errors "Failed creating a merkle tree", "Got VALIDATION_REQ failure"
On Cassandra 4.0.7 we are seeing Merkle tree repair errors , we are using cassandra-reaper to do continuous repairs, below is the exception
ERROR] [RequestResponseStage-9] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,131 RepairMessage.java:78 - 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 VALIDATION_REQ failed on /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
[ERROR] [RequestResponseStage-9] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairMessage.java:78 - 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 VALIDATION_REQ failed on /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
[ERROR] [RequestResponseStage-9] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairMessage.java:78 - 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 VALIDATION_REQ failed on /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
[ERROR] [RequestResponseStage-9] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairMessage.java:78 - 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 VALIDATION_REQ failed on /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
[ERROR] [RequestResponseStage-9] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairMessage.java:78 - 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 VALIDATION_REQ failed on /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
[WARN] [RepairJobTask:3] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairJob.java:177 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 replication.payloads_by_bucket sync failed
[WARN] [RepairJobTask:8] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,132 RepairJob.java:177 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 replication.segments sync failed
[WARN] [RepairJobTask:7] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,133 RepairJob.java:177 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 replication.replication_queue sync failed
[WARN] [RepairJobTask:11] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,133 RepairJob.java:177 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 replication.payload_register sync failed
[ERROR] [Repair#240941:1] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,134 RepairSession.java:321 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 Session completed with the following error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276|#7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]]] Got VALIDATION_REQ failure from /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.messages.RepairMessage$1.onFailure(RepairMessage.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.ResponseVerbHandler.doVerb(ResponseVerbHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.lambda$new$0(InboundSink.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:97)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:45)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundMessageHandler$ProcessMessage.run(InboundMessageHandler.java:432)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:165)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:137)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:119)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
[WARN] [RepairJobTask:3] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,134 RepairJob.java:177 - repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 replication.replication_queue_ptr sync failed
[ERROR] [Repair#240941:1] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,134 RepairRunnable.java:178 - Repair 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 failed:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair session 7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 for range [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]] failed with error [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276|#7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]]] Got VALIDATION_REQ failure from /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairRunnable$RepairSessionCallback.onFailure(RepairRunnable.java:698)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1056)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.forceShutdown(RepairSession.java:342)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession$1.onFailure(RepairSession.java:323)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276|#7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/replication_queue, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]]] Got VALIDATION_REQ failure from /<IP>:7000: UNKNOWN
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.messages.RepairMessage$1.onFailure(RepairMessage.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.ResponseVerbHandler.doVerb(ResponseVerbHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.lambda$new$0(InboundSink.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:97)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:45)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundMessageHandler$ProcessMessage.run(InboundMessageHandler.java:432)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:165)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:137)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:119)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,136 Validator.java:237 - Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/dc_1cae277e_6e2e_46d2_bffa_983557f6b155, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276|#7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/dc_1cae277e_6e2e_46d2_bffa_983557f6b155, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]]], /<IP>:7000 (see log for details)
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,137 ValidationManager.java:173 - Validation failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parent repair session with id = 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 has failed.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.getParentRepairSession(ActiveRepairService.java:690)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.getSSTablesToValidate(CassandraValidationIterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.<init>(CassandraValidationIterator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraTableRepairManager.getValidationIterator(CassandraTableRepairManager.java:51)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.getValidationIterator(ValidationManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.doValidation(ValidationManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.access$000(ValidationManager.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager$1.call(ValidationManager.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,137 CassandraDaemon.java:581 - Exception in thread Thread[ValidationExecutor:66,1,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parent repair session with id = 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 has failed.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.getParentRepairSession(ActiveRepairService.java:690)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.getSSTablesToValidate(CassandraValidationIterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.<init>(CassandraValidationIterator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraTableRepairManager.getValidationIterator(CassandraTableRepairManager.java:51)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.getValidationIterator(ValidationManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.doValidation(ValidationManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.access$000(ValidationManager.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager$1.call(ValidationManager.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,137 Validator.java:237 - Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/dc_1a116929_41ec_4be6_b561_0d42dad8caf7, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276|#7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 on replication/dc_1a116929_41ec_4be6_b561_0d42dad8caf7, [(-892119161849290738,-881535601694419919], (-3078145018521241272,-3075823683795731276], (7303356382144251816,7303733610091843383], (8313290647942866939,8331919689226408479]]], /<IP>:7000 (see log for details)
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,137 ValidationManager.java:173 - Validation failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parent repair session with id = 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 has failed.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.getParentRepairSession(ActiveRepairService.java:690)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.getSSTablesToValidate(CassandraValidationIterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.<init>(CassandraValidationIterator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraTableRepairManager.getValidationIterator(CassandraTableRepairManager.java:51)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.getValidationIterator(ValidationManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.doValidation(ValidationManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.access$000(ValidationManager.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager$1.call(ValidationManager.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,137 CassandraDaemon.java:581 - Exception in thread Thread[ValidationExecutor:66,1,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parent repair session with id = 7fbb5e40-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 has failed.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.getParentRepairSession(ActiveRepairService.java:690)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.getSSTablesToValidate(CassandraValidationIterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraValidationIterator.<init>(CassandraValidationIterator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.repair.CassandraTableRepairManager.getValidationIterator(CassandraTableRepairManager.java:51)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.getValidationIterator(ValidationManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.doValidation(ValidationManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager.access$000(ValidationManager.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationManager$1.call(ValidationManager.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:826)


The log messages you posted simply state that the validation tasks for the repair sessions which build Merkle trees for the replicas has failed but on their own won't explain why.
By definition, Cassandra repairs fix data inconsistencies between replicas. As such, the operation always involves multiple nodes so you can't just look at the logs on one node -- you need to cross-reference the repair messages across multiple replicas to get a full picture.
As you can see in some of the error messages, it explicitly instructs the operator to see log for details:
[ERROR] [ValidationExecutor:66] 2023-11-05 13:49:58,136 Validator.java:237 - \
  Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair #7fc76c30-7c14-11ee-a6b1-09b8491c94a6 \
  on replication/dc_1cae277e_6e2e_46d2_bffa_983557f6b155, [...]], \
  /<IP>:7000 (see log for details)

You need to view the logs on the replica where the validation task failed to find out the reason so you can figure out your next steps. Cheers!
